# Change expand and collapse image TreeView JavaFX 2.2

Tags: java, image, javafx-2, expand, treeviewitem

Is it possible to change the Expand and Collapse Images of a JavaFX 2.2 TreeVIew?

Change this image,

[image: Valid XHTML]

To an image like this (with +/-),

[image: Valid XHTML]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, this is possible with a little bit of css.
The CSS looks like this:

```
.tree-cell .tree-disclosure-node .arrow {
    -fx-shape: null;
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-background-image: url("plus-arrow.png");
}
.tree-cell:expanded .tree-disclosure-node .arrow {
    -fx-shape: null;
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-background-image: url("minus-arrow.png");
}
```

lg Kalasch

Comment: I added icons on 16x16 pixel dimension but they were cropped. On 10x10 pixels they were displayed great. Thank you.