# JavaFX: Use custom Node as collapse / expand branch switch for TreeView

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml, javafx-8

Is it possible to replace the expand and collapse arrow of a `TreeView` with a custom `Node` / shape (instead of an [image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15521806/1725096))?

Comment: Specifically, what kind of node do you want? The `-fx-shape` css property of the arrows will provide basic svg shapes.

Comment: @UlukBiy: Shame on me, you're absolutely right. Thanks! The default even consists of two styleable nodes. The only thing I will however have to deal with, is the "arrow" rotation.

Comment: There is a default solution for rotation also in there (caspian): `-fx-rotate: 90;` :), See .tree-cell:expanded .tree-disclosure-node .arrow

Comment: @UlukBiy: Great, I already thought about that there had to be something like this. If you like, you can enhance your comment to a short "acceptable" answer, of course. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-fx-shape` css property of the arrows provides basic SVG shapes.

```
.tree-cell .tree-disclosure-node .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-mark-color;
    -fx-padding: 0.333333em; /* 4 */
    -fx-shape: "M 0 -4 L 8 0 L 0 4 z";    // <-- change this default triangle shape
}

.tree-cell:expanded .tree-disclosure-node .arrow {
    -fx-rotate: 90;                      // maybe another svg shape instead
}
```