# how to change icon of treeview on clicking a button

Tags: image, treeview, javafx

I am having treeview with 5 children and each child is having "cry.jpg" image. Now if i select child1 in treeview and clicked on a button(change icon is button name) then "cry.jpg" should replace to "smile.jpg". is there a way to replace image at run time

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX8 treeTableView customize collapse root item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019077/javafx8-treetableview-customize-collapse-root-item)

Comment: in the above link, root node image is changing, in my case it was child (which is selected) image should change

Comment: Your use case seems similar enough to the linked answer that you could adapt it pretty easily.  Give it a go, and, if successful, you can post your solution as the answer to your question and mark it correct. (I'm not sure if there is some reputation limit for marking your own answers correct, but I think eventually with enough reputation, you can do that.)