# How to change collapse and expand icon for a particular treeview in javafx?

Tags: css, javafx, treeview

I need to apply CSS to change collapse/expand icons for a particular treeview in my JavaFX application. FX:ID for it is treeView. However I have many other treeviews in my application and I don't want those icons to be changed.

[Change expand and collapse image TreeView JavaFX 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521806/change-expand-and-collapse-image-treeview-javafx-2-2)

Above link provides a solution to apply CSS but that would change icons in all the treeViews. Is there any way I can apply CSS to particular treeView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a separate class to your TreeView and change its icon.

```
treeView.getStyleClass().add("my-tree-view");
```

and change the icons only for this treeView

```
.my-tree-view > .virtual-flow> .clipped-container > .sheet > .tree-cell .tree-disclosure-node .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
.my-tree-view > .virtual-flow> .clipped-container > .sheet > .tree-cell:expanded .tree-disclosure-node .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I had this idea..but this doesn't seem to work :(
I'm opening another stage as a popup from my main stage. And this treeview is present in the new stage. Anything needs to be done to handle that?

Comment: You need to load the stylesheet and add it to either the scene of the new Stage or directly to the treeview.

Comment: You're right. I had forgotten to load the css. However after adding, other styles are getting reflected. But not the treeview one.

Comment: What style did you use?

Comment: scene.getStylesheets().add("styles.css");

I loaded the css with the above..then I added treeView.getStyleClass().add("my-tree-view"); in the controller. 

In styles.css, I added the code that is there in your answer.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it should work. Can you try the MCVE in the question?